# Dish installer damaged the electric panel box

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

A few years ago (like 8 or 9 years) we had a television dish installer come to our house and install the dish. After using it for a couple of years we got rid of it but obviously left the dish attached to the house to avoid filing any holes in the siding.

Some time back I noticed that one of the bolts that he used to install the dish frame from outside had pierced through my main electric panel box inside the garage. Thankfully it did not damage any wiring or circuit breakers.

What can I do now? Do I need to replace the entire box? Is this a code issue. I want to do the solution and rectification right!!

Please advise.

Regards
Sid

Comment: It may be sufficient to simply remove the offending screw. What size hole will be left after the screw is removed? If the hole is fairly small there may be no need to plug it.

Comment: Thanks Greg - How can I plug the hole? Silicon Gel. Should I get a  licensed electrician do the needful?

Comment: As Greg mentions it is even required by code to have up to 1/4” holes in the box that are arranged for drainage. They were using the box for a ground since it did not damage anything leave it in place if you want, take it out if you want but it won’t hurt things and may end up being used in the future you never know. If you want to plug it use some paintable calking in it and call it good.

Comment: Hi @GregHill and Ed Beal - Thanks. The hole could be greater that a 1/4 inch. I am going through a check list of things at home because we are debating a sale of property. My main concern is to avoid post inspections tasks to handle. Prefer things be correct before.

Comment: Can you post photos of the offending hole?